# How to execute/run puppet class

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet. I want to know how to execute/run a simple puppet class. Below is the class I am trying to execute using

```
puppet apply classExample.pp
```

**classExample.pp** is the file in which class is written.
This code just compiles the class and nothing happens.
How to execute this class?

```
 # A class with no parameters
class exampleClass {

 #create a directory
  file {"create directory":
    path => '/root/rahil/puppet/puppetDemo/tmp',
    ensure => "directory",
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you did is [defining a class](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html#lang_class_define).
But you also need to [declare it](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html#lang_class_declare).

For the sake of the example, it could look like this:

```
# A class with no parameters
class example_class {

  #create a directory
  file {"create directory":
    path => '/root/rahil/puppet/puppetDemo/tmp',
    ensure => "directory",
  }

}

class { 'example_class': }
```

Please note that I changed the name to `example_class` as upper case letters [should not be used in class names](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_reserved.html).
And also note that usually you don't define and declare classes in the same file.
How that is done is a bigger topic, see [Modules fundamentals Documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/modules_fundamentals.html#modules_fundamentals) for a start.

Comment: Most documentation uses `class { '...': }` for declaration these days, but I personally prefer `include <class>` whenever possible. See the [discussion](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#include-like-vs-resource-like) in the documentation.

Comment: The link for https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html is now broken. Do you have an up to date one?